# No DNS in resolv.conf when using dhcp

Tags: networking, dhcp, dns

Firstly, I have to mention that I am configuring the network interfaces manually by modifying `dhcpcd.conf` and `wpa_supplicant.conf`. I need to do it like this because of the project that I work on.

**wpa_supplicant.conf:**

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1

country=RO

network={
ssid="someSSID"
psk="somePassword"
}
```

**dhcpcd.conf:**

```
interface wlan0
hostname DisplayWiFi
clientid DisplayWiFi

interface eth0
noipv4
noipv6

append domain-name-servers 1.1.1.1;
```

`append domain-name-servers 1.1.1.1;` does nothing.

The only DNS I have in `resolv.conf` is 8.8.8.8 which I've manually written there.

`dhcpcd.conf` does not write any DNS.

I have tried on both Ethernet and WiFi but no DNS.

How can I fix this ?

On a related note, I was wondering if it's possible to hard-code the Google 8.8.8.8 DNS somewhere where it can't be changed by `dhcpcd.conf` even when configuring static addresses so that the raspberry can always have something like a fallback DNS.

Comment: Have you read & understood `man dhcpcd` and `man dhcpcd.conf` ??

Comment: Yes and mostly no.
I believe that the only way to specify DNS using `dhcpcd` is by using `static domain_name_servers`. So, I've turned to **resolvconf.conf** which actually has an option called: `name_servers_append` which can: "`Append name servers to the dynamically generated list`". As such, I've went and added `name_servers_append="1.1.1.1"` to **resolvconf.conf**. This does the following: if the interface is set to DHCP, then it writes only the `1.1.1.1` DNS to **resolv.conf**; if it's set to StaticIP, then it appends `1.1.1.1` as `nameserver 1.1.1.1` after the specified static DNS.

Comment: OK - good luck.

Comment: @Seamus Does my solution seem viable to you ?

Comment: ***To me:*** No - it does not. And I must be honest with you: I don't spend much time thinking about issues that users create for themselves when they change their default network configuration without offering good reasons for doing so. I've tried to help in the past, and it's been time wasted.

Comment: @Seamus Fantastic attitude. Some of us have real reasons for changing network configurations manually. If you are unable to help, please don't comment. I came looking for a similar answer.

Comment: @colpanic73: `Fantastic attitude`... Your sarcasm is noted. But before getting so snarky, please note that the OP ***requested*** my opinion.